# Entity Framework ThenInclude doesn't include properties of the grandchild

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework ThenInclude doesn't include any properties of the grandchild. When I try to access the property "Total" of the "GrandChild" I get an error "CS1061 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Total' and no accessible extension method 'Total'". The intellosense doesn't work with "GrandChild" at all. It works fine with the "Child", but not with the "GrandChild". When I make the request from Postman I can see that Entity includes "GrandChild" and it has property "Total" for sure (and all other properties).

```
var products = dbf.Products
                .Include(a=>a.Child)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.GrandChild)          
                .Where(c => c.ProId >72200);

            foreach(var p in products)
            {
               p.Child.GrandChild.Total// I get error here

            }
```

Comment: [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.count?view=netcore-3.1) does not have property `Total` it has property `Count`.

Comment: `GrandChild` is a bad name for the property, it should be something like `GrandChildren`, that should give you a better idea of what is going wrong. Instead you need to loop over that collection, or do something like `Child.GrandChild.First().Total`

Comment: Thanks for this piece of valuable information. But the question is how I can get access to the property using ThenInclude (and what is the purpose of ThenInclude if it doesn't allow the access to properties?

Comment: YOu can not. ThenInclude is not responsible for ACCESSING the property. It makes sure GrandChild (again, very bad naming for a oclection) is loaded, you need to iterate the children in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for access all total properties of GrandChild :

```
var totals = p.Child.GrandChild.Select(gc=> gc.Total);
```

But if you want get total grandchilds (count of grandchilds) you should try this:

```
var count = p.Child.GrandChild.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear, or?

GrandChild is an ICollection (which we could see if you would provide the relevant class definitions). There is no Total function on an ICollection. Period. Never was. This is not an Entity Framewor kquestion at all - you bascially assume that ThenInclude will magically provide a proeprty Total on an ICollection.

How is this supposed to work, given that Total requires to know how to add and unless the element in the collection is a scalar of any type that is simply not possible.

Use logic to calculate the total.